Custom sorting a dataframe based on multiple columns
Below is an example dataframe:



Name
State
Location




Jamie
New York
Manhattan


Mary
Ohio
Downtown Cleveland


John
New York
Flushing Queens


Sam
Ohio
Lakewood Cleveland


James
Ohio
Beachwood Cleveland


Perry
New York
Uptown Manhattan


Diane
New York
Briarwood Queens


Julie
New York
Lower Manhattan



I would like to sort this dataframe so that they are grouped by State and Location. In the case of Location, all nuances of Manhattan are grouped together and likewise for the others. The Location column should be custom sorted in the order of [Manhattan, Queens, Cleveland]
The result should be something like that shown below:



Name
State
Location




Jamie
New York
Manhattan


Perry
New York
Uptown Manhattan


Julie
New York
Lower Manhattan


John
New York
Flushing Queens


Diane
New York
Briarwood Queens


Mary
Ohio
Downtown Cleveland


Sam
Ohio
Lakewood Cleveland


James
Ohio
Beachwood Cleveland



I tried the solution posted here. But for it to work I will need to include all the possibilities in column Location. What's the best way to achieve this?

By "local" do you mean locale?

I meant column 'Local". I edited the table to rename is to 'Location" to avoid confusion.

How about sorting by the last word of the Location column?

the descriptor for the location is not always the last word.

Try:
# extract required areas
df["tmp"] = df.Location.str.extract(r"(Manhattan|Queens|Cleveland)")

# define order
df["tmp"] = pd.Categorical(
    df["tmp"], categories=["Manhattan", "Queens", "Cleveland"], ordered=True
)

# sort
df = df.sort_values(by=["State", "tmp"]).drop(columns="tmp")

print(df)

Prints:
    Name     State             Location
0  Jamie  New York            Manhattan
5  Perry  New York     Uptown Manhattan
7  Julie  New York      Lower Manhattan
2   John  New York      Flushing Queens
6  Diane  New York     Briarwood Queens
1   Mary      Ohio   Downtown Cleveland
3    Sam      Ohio   Lakewood Cleveland
4  James      Ohio  Beachwood Cleveland

